# How can I create a Mac Address Book plug-in that also appears in Spotlight?

Tags: macos, mac, contacts, plugins, quicklook-plugin

I've installed a great little app called PushDialer for my Mac that is letting my initiate iPhone calls to contacts remotely from my Mac.

It seems to work by installing an Address Book plug-in, so that when I click on a phone number in the Contacts app, 'Dial with iPhone' appears as a choice on the context menu.

However, if I search for a contact using Spotlight, then when I click the phone number on Spotlight's 'quick look' window, this context menu item is not visible.  Instead, only the three default OS X items are there - 'Show in large type', 'Send message' and 'FaceTime'.

Is it possible to add a Spotlight context menu item for Contacts in the same way?  I'd much prefer to make my calls without having to open the Contacts app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears Spotlight does not make use of [Address Book plug-ins](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/Actions.html).

Extra menu items added by Skype also fail to appear in the Spotlight preview.

It is worth providing [feedback to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html) asking for this functionality to be added. It would greatly improve Spotlight.

### Context Menu in Contacts.app:

[image: Context menu in Contacts.app of OS X 10.8]

### Context Menu of Contact in Spotlight:

[image: Context menu of a Contact in Spotlight of OS X 10.8]

Comment: Thanks Graham, I have indeed provided feedback to Apple in this regard and would ask that you also do the same.  I can't technically mark this as a correct answer just yet, but if nobody can prove otherwise will do so in future.

Comment: @CarlosP You can always revisit a question that you have ticked the "answer" button and change which answer is selected. It's up to you when to pull the trigger, since without an "answered" you're likely to get far more guesses so it's a lever you have influence whether a topic is shut down or still open.

Comment: @bmike thanks for the helpful advice, I won't leave it too much longer then.

Comment: Guess it was about time.